# Ruby matching the particular word

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to match the particular word in a string but it is matching the whole string

```
doc = "<span>Hi welcome to world</span>"
puts doc.match(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/)
```

This code prints the whole string

Output:

```
<span>Hi welcome to world</span>
```

But i want only

```
Hi welcome to world
```

The another problem is that the output for this program is just an integer

```
doc = "<span>Hi welcome to world</span>"
puts doc =~ (/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/)
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: `Nokogiri.parse(doc).at_css('span').text` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put first match group:

```
puts doc.match(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/)[1]
# => Hi welcome to world
```

To answer your another question, from [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E):

> Match—If obj is a Regexp, use it as a pattern to match against str,and returns the position the match starts, or nil if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

After matching with a RegEx you can use $1, $2, ... to output matched groups. So you could simply do:

```
doc.match(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/)
puts $1
```

You could take a look at [What are Ruby's numbered global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673847/what-are-rubys-numbered-global-variables) for a detailed explanation about other variables such as $'.